# Writing to an Excel document from Html form

Tags: html, excel, vbscript

On an internal network I want to write what colleagues fill in on an internal web form to an excel database.

After some research I came up with the below code but I can't seem to get it to work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
Sub Divert ()
    Dim iRow
    Set objExcel = CreateObject ("Excel. Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("G:\Bournemouth\CorporateShared\General Insurance\GI complaint Team\Baxter Diverted\diverted.xlsx")
    objExcel.Application.Visible = True
    ObjWorkbook.Windows (1).Visible = True
    Set XlSheet =objWorkbook.Sheets (1)
    XlSheet.Activate

    iRow = 1
    With objExcel
    Do while .Cells (iRow, 1).value <> ""
    .Cells (iRow, 1).activate
    iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop

    .Cells (iRow, 1).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("date") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 2).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("date1") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 3).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("name") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 4).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("acti") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 5).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("supwho") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 6).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("prowhi") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 7).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("trawha") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 8).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("hanwho") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 9).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("prowha") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 10).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("surwho") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 11).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("letwho") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 12).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("miwha") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 13).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("miwho") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 14).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("time") (0).Value
    .Cells (iRow, 15).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("desc") (0).Value

    MsgBox "Diverted time updated”, vbinformation

    Document.GetElementsByName ("date") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("date1") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("name") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("acti") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("supwho") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("prowhi") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("trawha") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("hanwho") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("prowha") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("surwho") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("letwho") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("miwha") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("miwho") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("time") (0).Value=""
    Document.GetElementsByName ("desc") (0).Value=""

    End With
    ObjWorkbook.Save
    ObjWorkbook.Close
    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
</script>
```

I fill in the form and click my submit button code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="Divert()" value="Submit" />
```

and it doesn't save to the document at all and doesn't bring up the confirmation box

Could there be a setting i've not set somewhere on the excel document or something similar, from what i can see the code should work?

Thanks

Comment: What is not working? Please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: I fill in the form and click my submit button code: <input type="button" onclick="Divert()" value="Submit" /> and it doesn't save to the document at all and doesn't bring up the confirmation box

Comment: Could there be a setting i've not set somewhere on the excel document or something similar, from what i can see the code should work?

Comment: I have no experience with VBScript in HTML, but try: `onClick="vbscript:Divert()"`

Comment: Also not sure if the space in `CreateObject ("Excel. Application")` should be there.

Comment: Does it throw an error? As mentioned by @moffeltje the space in `CreateObject("Excel. Application")` should not be there. Is this in the actual code or just a typo in here?

Comment: Thanks, the space was actually there, so i've now removed. No error is thrown it just does nothing.

Comment: Silly question: have you debugged the code? Is it executing every line?

Comment: I've debugged and it is coming up with Divert is undefined, i'm using compatibility back to IE:10 in the meta tags otherwise vbscript isn't suypported as far as i'm aware